# When dealing with multiple functions in a program. How is it best to deal with their logic?

Tags: c++, console-application

I am currently getting to grips with how to correctly implement multiple functions in my programs and I think I have got the right idea but I am just wanting to clarify.

When putting some logic into a particular function, should I be handling the end the result in that function or bringing it back to my "main function"? I am aware this is probably an ambiguous question so I have posted my code here to try and help matters.

The program simply adds a string to a vector but I am wondering whats the best approach to handle it.

Thank you so much in advance.

Program 1.

```
std::vector<std::string> favouriteGames; //Stores favourite games


int menu = 0; //Menu navigation
std::cout << "1: Add Game. 2: Remove Game. 3: List Games. 4: Exit.";
std::cin >> menu;

//Menu
switch (menu)
{
case 1:
    favouriteGames.push_back(AddGame());
    break;

case 2:
    //favouriteGames.erase(RemoveGame);
    break;

case 3:
    //ListGames();
    break;

case 4:
    break;

default:
    std::cout << "Please enter correct data.";
}

//Add game
std::string AddGame()
{
    std::string gameName;

    int menu = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter name of game you wish to add.";
    std::cin >> gameName;

    return gameName;
}
```

Program 2.
Or like this when the function is solely handling the data and doesn't return anything.

```
void AddGame(std::vector<std::string> favouriteGames);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> favouriteGames; //Stores favourite games


    int menu = 0; //Menu navigation
    std::cout << "1: Add Game. 2: Remove Game. 3: List Games. 4: Exit.";
    std::cin >> menu;

    //Menu
    switch (menu)
    {
    case 1:
        AddGame(favouriteGames);
        break;

    case 2:
        //favouriteGames.erase(RemoveGame);
        break;

    case 3:
        //ListGames();
        break;

    case 4:
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Please enter correct data.";
    }

    //Keep Window open
    std::string barn;
    std::cin >> barn;

    return 0;
}

//Add game
void AddGame(std::vector<std::string> favouriteGames)
{
    std::string gameName;

    int menu = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter name of game you wish to add.";
    std::cin >> gameName;

    favouriteGames.push_back(gameName);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Programmers.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program I.

In general, your functions should have *one job*. It makes them re-usable and helps to keep your interfaces clean and stable.

In this case, that means your function is actually named wrongly. It should be something like `requestGameName()`.

You could then also hive the `.push_back` into its own, second function (`addGame()`?) though that may be overkill in your initial version. Still, one day, adding a game may involve more lines of code that trigger you to move all of that into another function.

Comment: My view is to write requestGameName now, and just use push_back for the moment.  If you find yourself writing the same two lines of code three times - move it into a function.  If you find yourself writing the same five lines of code twice - move it into a function.  If it becomes 20 lines (even once) - move it into a function.

Comment: Will do, thank you. Can I ask how's best to name functions? My understanding was to name the function on what it did but yours seems to be a bit more literal.

Comment: @RyanSwann: The function requests a game name (from `std::cin`/the user). How is that not naming it after what it does?

Comment: I can see now why not sure what my line of thinking was. Error on my part.

Comment: "Can I ask how best to name functions?"  After long debate!  Naming things is hard.  "There are two hard problems in Computer Science:  1.  Naming things; 2. Cache Invalidation." and not forgetting "3.  Off-by-one errors."

Comment: @MartinBonner: "4. Remembering that computer science and software development have next to nothing in common and that the former would be better called 'computing science'."